# Link error during gcc compile with makefile

Tags: c, gcc, linker, makefile

(Before moving on, 
the absence of frees and writing variables which are never used in the codes,
 
are intended for testing a tool)
I wrote codes like these and Makefile like this:

unread_two.h

```
#ifndef __UNREAD_TWO_H
#define __UNREAD_TWO_H

const int SIZEOF_INT = sizeof(int);
int addTwo();
```

unread_twomain.c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "unread_two.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *x;

    x = (int *)malloc(SIZEOF_INT);
    x = addTwo();
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

unread_two.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unread_two.h>

int addTwo()
{
    int *y, *z, sum;
    y = (int *)malloc(SIZEOF_INT);
    z = (int *)malloc(SIZEOF_INT);

    *y = 3;
    sum = *y + *y;
    return sum;
}
```

Makefile

```
CC=gcc
CCFLAGS=-g

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CCFLAGS)

all: unread_two
clobber: clean
    rm -f *~ \#`\# core

clean:
    rm -f unread_two *.o

unread_two: unread_twomain.o unread_two.o

unread_twomain.o: unread_two.h

unread_two.o: unread_two.h
```

and when I put make all, this message appears:

```
unread_twomain.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `SIZEOF_INT'
unread_two.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What things should I fix?

Comment: The quickest fix is to add `static` in front of the definition of `SIZEOF_INT` in the header (but it isn't likely to be a good long-term solution, if only because you could end up with two object files that disagree on what the value of SIZEOF_INT actually is).  In C++, the constant would effectively be treated like that, but C creates two initialized variables, one per source file, and you can't link those two source files together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be *defining* `SIZEOF_INT` in a header, otherwise you'll get multiple definitions when you include this header in more than one compilation unit, as you have seen. Instead *declare* it in a header and *define* it in a source file:

```
// unread_two.h

extern const int SIZEOF_INT;         // *declare* SIZEOF_INT
```

```
// unread_two.c

const int SIZEOF_INT = sizeof(int);  // *define* SIZEOF_INT
```

Alternatively in this particular case you might be justified in doing it the "old skool" way, with a macro:

```
// unread_two.h

#define SIZEOF_INT sizeof(int)
```

Comment: @LocustSpectre For constants I would recommend the macro way, allows the compiler to optimise better. Also you should accept an answer if this fixed your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have *two* errors, the one you report and another more devious bug.

The problem you are getting an error about is that the constant `SIZEOF_INT` is defined in all source file you include the header file in. Include guards only protect against multiple inclusion in the same source file (or translation unit technically speaking), but not agains you including the same file in multiple sources. This means that the compiler will create a definition of `SIZEOF_INT` in both `unread_twomain.o` and `unread_two.o`, which the linker will then complain about.

The solution to this is to only *declare* the constant in the header file, and then *define* it in a single source file.

---

The other problem is that in `main` you create `x` as a pointer, and allocate memory for it (by the way, you should not typecast the return of `malloc`), and then assing the result from `addTwo` to this pointer. But `addTwo` doesn't return a pointer, it returns a straight value, so you make the pointer `x` point to the address `6` which is not exactly what you intend to do I guess. This will cause *undefined behavior* when you then try to free the memory pointed to by `x`, most likely causing a crash.

In your program you don't have to use pointers *at all*. Just use normal non-pointer variables:

```
int addTwo()
{
    int y = 3;
    int sum = y + y;

    return sum;
}
```

And

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x = addTwo();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed first by fixing header, and the second one by adding *. I need those variables as pointer to see if my tool detects memory locations which are never been read since initialization.

Comment: BTW, would you explain more about "(by the way, you should not typecast the return of malloc)?"

Comment: @LocustSpectre Typecasting the return will hide if you forget to include the correct header file. That might cause you a warning but still compiles otherwise fine, but it will most likely cause a weird crash when running the program.